# UITableViewCell Grouped Frame extends beyond cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating a custom cell setup. My issue is when I add a subview to the cell and make it align to the right of the cell it goes beyond the right edge of the cell. Apparently the frame goes beyond the visible edge of the cell and onto the background.

I need the right edge to be the inside of the cell. What should I do?

Comment: add it and subtract with the margin value, of course you will have to experiment to the right value. this is the normal behaviour of a UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it manually and just detect if the device was an ipad and change the frame.